# Commented out "for" statement results in 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, types, beautifulsoup, tags

Appreciate any insights to this weird error I'm getting. Thanks in advance! I'm still trying to learn  BeautifulSoup structures and when Tag.Elements are available. So in Example 1, it's pretty plain and came out as expected. In Example 2, I was trying to write a `for` loop, wasn't happy and commented it out.

1) When I ran my code again (after saving new changes), I'm getting this error: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len(). Weird. Anyone know why I might be seeing this error? I double checked that those lines were commented out, saved, ran. Then deleted the comments, saved, ran it again. Same.

```
EXAMPLE 1:
chapter = soup.find('h3', text=re.compile('chapter', re.IGNORECASE))
print(type(chapter))
print(chapter.string)
p_tag = 'p'
item = chapter
print(item)
print(type(item))

=== RESTART: D:\Scripts\Python\batch content editing\get_tree_position.py ===
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
CHAPTER ONE 
CHAPTER ONE
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>


EXAMPLE 2:
chapter = soup.find('h3', text=re.compile('chapter', re.IGNORECASE))
print(type(chapter))
print(chapter.string)
#print(type(soup.chapter))
p_tag = 'p'
item = chapter
print(item.string)
print(type(item)) 
#for item in h3.findNextSiblings():
#   getattr(item, 'name')

=== RESTART: D:\Scripts\Python\batch content editing\get_tree_position.py ===
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Scripts\Python\batch content editing\get_tree_position.py", line 28, in <module>
    big_soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 246, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: The comments are not the cause of the error. The Traceback shows that your error is happening on line 28, but you haven't included that code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this was an editor or mousepad error in a completely different section. I found it at the same time berklem posted. So thank you, berklem! And apologies...